# Load not equally distributed among AWS Spark slaves

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, apache-spark

I have set up an AWS EMR cluster with Spark 1.4. I have set up one master node and two slave nodes. Looking at the load distribution, it seems like one slave is always maxed out while the other one is not doing much. Has anyone faced similar issue? What might be causing this?

Note: I am trying to run Spark MLLib for generating recommendation. So it pulls data from Elasticsearch and does recommendation computation using Spark. One slave is always maxed out on Network usage while the other seems to be using minimal resource and almost idle. The master is using 10 GB of network while each slave is using 1 GB.

Comment: It sounds like a data skew. Have you tried repartitioning your data?

Comment: Is this application using client or deployment mode?   How many executors are actually running?

Comment: @ChristopherB - It is running in cluster mode (Yarn cluster). I tried using different number of executors ranging from 6 to 60 but the pattern is always the same.

Comment: @GlennieHellesSindholt - No haven't tried repartitioning the data. Looks more to do with the aws configuration, but not really sure.

Comment: Spark on YARN on EMR behaves the same as any YARN cluster; this doesn't sound like AWS config. What is your slave instance type? How much memory are you requesting for driver and executor? When you select 6 executors, do all 6 actually run?

Comment: I tried using r3.8xlarge instance for driver and 2 m3.xlarge instances for slaves. I had not explicitly specified executor memory though.

Comment: When using yarn-cluster the driver will not run on the master but in a container on a slave. Take a look at the Spark UI via Resource Manager while running or the history server to determine actual executor usage.